# Is it possible to have two HDD's, and both be primary?

Tags: windows, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I accidentally made my new hard drive (the non system drive) my primary partition](https://superuser.com/questions/123703/i-accidentally-made-my-new-hard-drive-the-non-system-drive-my-primary-partition)

Here is my configuration:

C: - system/Windows XP HDD

D: - empty

I just added a new hard drive (D) and formatted it and made it a primary HDD.

Since then Windows hasn't been able to boot. Is the computer able to have both the system and the new HDD as primary? If not, then that is why Windows isn't booting.

If it IS possible, then I have no idea what the problem is.

Any help or thoughts would be fantastic! thanks!

Comment: @qwerty2: you've already asked one question about this (two counting the one posted to StackOverflow that was migrated here); this one is not appreciably different from the earlier one.  please don't post multiple times.  instead, edit your first question so that the problem is clear, and we can help you there.

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/123703/i-accidentally-made-my-new-hard-drive-the-non-system-drive-my-primary-partition

Comment: note that you can have *multiple primary partitions* (up to 4) on a single hard drive; this is normal.  you can also have partitions that are set as *active*; only one partition should be set active.  (this was already mentioned by someone on your other question.)  *this is not the same term as "primary hard drive".*  (and there's no such thing as a "secondary partition".)

Comment: Sorry about that quack, this topic was more a question of whether or not it was possible to have two HDDs as primary. I understand what you're saying about having multiple primary partitions on a single drive. When I went into Disk Management, and formatted my new drive, and set it up as Primary, would that in any way conflict with my system HDD? It's just strange and coincidental how as soon as I formatted and partitioned my new HDD, Windows wouldn't boot up. And now it seems to need the new, empty HDD. When I remove it, a warning pops up on screen saying it can't be found.

Comment: you're still confusing the terms *drive* and *partition* -- Disk Management doesn't allow you to set any *drives* as "primary", although it does allow you to create (many) *primary partitions* -- it's the *active* flag mentioned previously that is confusing your BIOS.  note that a "drive letter" doesn't refer to an actual hard drive, it refers to a partition.

Comment: what kind of drives are these, anyway?  IDE or SATA?  how are they connected to the motherboard -- one or two flat ribbon cables (IDE), or do they each have their own thin data cable (SATA)?  if IDE, are they both on one ribbon cable or does each drive have its own?

Comment: They're both SATA drives. I read somewhere that XP has trouble with SATA hard drives and it won't allow XP to be installed on them? Is that true? I was planning on (as a LAST resort) installing XP on my new HDD, and copying over the files I need from my previous system HDD. Otherwise, any idea what could cause this problem? I found this article, but not sure if it applies: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/228004 - it's just strange how taking out the new HDD makes the computer warn me about it being missing, not sure why it matters if an empty HDD is missing...

Comment: it's a SATA controller in AHCI mode that XP has trouble with, tho you can install XP by slipstreaming drivers, or by setting your controller to IDE-emulation mode instead of AHCI in the BIOS.  yes, that link is basically the problem (as far as i can tell).  its possible that when you set the other drive partition as *active*, Windows unset the *active* flag on its system partition, which is why it's trying to find system files on the new partition.

Comment: I'm using a Partition utility via a bootable CD, and it let's me see what's happening with each drive and partition. Disk 1 (the system drive) has 3 partitions: 1: FAT, 62MB, hidden, Primary. 2: NTFS, 465GB, Active, Primary. 3: Unallocatied, 10mb, None, Logical. - Seems like it is active after all? I would try installing XP on my new HDD, but I get a STOP error blue screen during the loading screen of the installer. Something about a pci.sys file.  This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't have two primary drives on the same IDE cable. If you make D: a secondary drive your machine should boot.

Having said that it could be that it's finding D: first and as it's a primary drive it stops looking, but as it's empty there's nothing for it to boot from.

You could try swapping the drives over, but you should just have one primary and one secondary drive.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I've just run Partition Wizard from a bootable CD, and it's showing that both Disk 1 (the system disk) has 2 partitions, both primary. Disk 2 (the brand new HDD), has 1 partition and is also primary. Not sure how this can be since you said there can't be two HDD's as primary?

I've tried swapping the two HDDs around, but that doesn't make a difference, it still comes up with the same error message when botting up:

"Windows XP could not start because the following file is missing or corrupt: \WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CONFIG\SYSTEM"

Any thoughts would be v appreciated

Comment: @qwerty2 - take the second drive out - can you boot now?

Comment: Unfortunately not, same problem. I only had the C system drive in, rebooted, still won't boot the OS. Any ideas? Sorry to bug you about this but I'm pulling my hair out

Comment: By the way, this time is says "Drive 1 not found: SErial ATA, SATA-1. Alert! Failed to detect one or more drives during POST. Strike F1 key to continue"

Comment: @qwerty2 - I think you've reached the limit of my knowledge in this area. Can you change the state of the partitions from Partition Wizard? I'm guessing not, because otherwise you'd have already tried that.

Comment: No it won't let me do anything like that. I can copy the contents of my system drive to my new hard drive, that might be a last resort, and hope that it will boot Windows off the new HDD. 

I just don't understand why it says that a HDD is missing when I remove the new empty drive. Why would the computer care if a HDD is missing, there's nothing on it! No problems if you can't help further, I appreciate your thoughts so far

Comment: @ChrisF: see this user's earlier question for some (very confusing) context.

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* is that when you made it primary this replaced the first `C:` drive as primary.

I would try changing the primary back to `C:` in the [BIOS settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/BIOS-frequently-asked-questions) because the computer is looking for an operating system on `D:` and finding none to boot up.

To answer your other question, no you can't have two primary drives.

Comment: Unfortunately the BIOS on my Dell machine doesn't let me change partitions on the drives. As I said above, I've just turn Partition Wizard from a bootable CD, and it's showing that both Disk 1 (the system disk) has 2 partitions, both primary. Disk 2 (the brand new HDD), has 1 partition and is also primary. Not sure how this can be since you said there can't be two HDD's as primary?

It still comes up with the same error message when botting up:

"Windows XP could not start because the following file is missing or corrupt: \WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CONFIG\SYSTEM"

Any thoughts would be v appreciated